# EF Core: one to many isn't eager loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

Given the object model of Post has many PostTranslations, I set up two objects:

```
public partial class Post{
    public Post()   {
        PostTranslations = new HashSet<PostTranslation>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PostTranslation> PostTranslations { get; set; }
}

public partial class PostTranslation {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

In my context class, in the OnModelBuilding, I have the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>(entity => {
    entity.ToTable("Posts");
    entity
    .HasMany<PostTranslation>(x => x.PostTranslations)
    .WithOne(g => g.Post)
    .HasForeignKey(g=>g.PostId);
});
```

In my repository, I call the following:

```
db.Posts.Include(t=>t.PostTranslations).ToList();
```

But upon examining the generated SQL, PostTranslations is never joined, and the hashset on the Post object is always zero. There are translations and they are correctly joined in the database. I can get PostTranslations out of the datacontext if I query them directly. But I can't seem to get EFCore to eager load them with a simple .Include statement.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
The SQL that is generated is this:

```
SELECT [f].[Id],  [f].[Name] FROM [common].[Posts] AS [f]
```

I was expected to see a left join in there to PostTranslations so after I iterated the variables in the ToList(), the translations would be there.  And the 'common' schema is set in the modelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("common");
```

[image: Console Logging]

Comment: Everything looks good. There must be a second query for loading the `PostTranslations` after main `Posts` query. Hope the code is as shown, e.g. you are not setting the `PostTranslation.Post` property in the constructor or doing other fancy stuff in the constructor/navigation property getter setters etc.?

Comment: Are you sure there is only a single SQL query being executed here? As Ivan states, this would come through as 2 distinct SELECT statements.

Comment: @IvanStoev why should there be a second call? OP's query as is should be enough

Comment: @mxmissile This is how EF Core processes loading related sub collections (one query per collection). It's a different approach from EF6 single union query.

Comment: @IvanStoev What is `.Include(...)` used for then?

Comment: @mxmissile For the same as in EF6 - to load(include) the related data in the materialized result. Just the *implementation* is different.

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you for clarifying

Comment: @IvanStoev The code posted is exactly what I've got.  Nothing in the class constructors.

Comment: @Josh are you *sure* your not seeing a second query in your log?

Comment: @mxmissile Yes.  I added an output picture.  I'm iterating the list and doing a .First on the first item and that is when the error is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this was a namespace issue.  This was a refactored repository, and at the top of it, there was:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

With that namespace, the .Include statement was compiled correctly, but EFCore didn't pick up the relationships.  Add:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

and suddenly the SQL is generating the joins correctly for eager loads.